# Number Formatting hundredths and thousandths

Tags: excel, vba

I have a graph and don't want to create any extra columns, so I want to format the axis of the graph to multiply by `10`.

Does anyone know how to create a custom number format in Excel to display the number in thousandths ie the number but 1,000 times greater?

Comment: Question unclear. Show what you tried.

Comment: It's not unclear, was understood and answered perfectly succinctly below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0"000"` or `0",000"` might work for you.

Comment: I'm aware of the comma already being in the second one but am trying to do the same just multiplying it by 10 and get commas and cannot figure it out

Comment: @Lererferler You cannot use formatting with other than multiples of 1,000.  For your graphing issue, you might try a "helper column" with the math the way you want it.

Comment: No offense but I did say in the question I didn't want any extra columns, the file is big enough already. I know its a very simple solution to create some more columns but I would rather learn as much as I can about the program rather than take the easy way out. They are in multiples of 1000, I have used the above formatting to multiply 100 to 1000. It's not possible now to put a comma in it?

Comment: @JustinMcCartney I misunderstood the question.  Thought he wanted to enter 1000 and display it as 1.  (DUH -- sometimes I see what I want to see, and not what is really there:  I saw the thousand**th**s when what was meant was probably thousands, and that led to my error)

Comment: @Lererferler And I confused myself by not reading the other part of your question clearly, thinking where you wrote thousand**th**s that you wanted to divide, rather than multiply as you stated clearly elsewhere.

Comment: No worries, Ron. And thank you Justin, that worked perfectly also